# What's the Ord(4) in $\mathbb{Z}^∗_{15}$?

Tags: encryption

What is the Ord(4) in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15}$

I understand the basis of Ord(x) in that for $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15}$ Ord(1)=1 since $1^1=1$

So i assume Ord(4) for $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15}$ is Ord(4)= x since $7^x=1$

Answer (score 5):

The order of an element $g$ in a group is the smallest positive integer $x$ such that $g^x$ is equal to the identity element ( $1$ in this case) in that group. So e.g. the order of $7$ in $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15}$ is $4$ because:

$$7^1 \equiv 7 \text{ mod } 15$$
$$7^2 \equiv 49 \equiv 4 \text{ mod } 15$$
$$7^3 \equiv 28 \equiv 13 \text{ mod } 15$$
$$7^4 \equiv 91 \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 15$$

That should be enough information to solve for the order of $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15}$.